# Javascript: Access function within deep object on parse

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have an object

```js
var object1 = {
  object2: {
    function1: function(a, b, c, d, e) {
      //do some stuff with those parameters
      console.log('values are ' + a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c + ' ' + d);
    },
    function2: object1.object2.function1(2, 3, 4, 5)
  }
}
```

Why the line `function2: object1.object2.function1(2, 3, 4, 5)` line throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'object2' of undefined` and how can I make that work?

UPDATE: the answer is marked.

Thank you

Comment: `object1` and `object1.object2` aren't fully constructed at the time when you attempt to call `object1.object2.function1(...)`. Hence the error.

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to solve with that object structure, or are you just experimenting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Comment: @wZVanG thank you, I think that's what I need, I will test and let you all know.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because scope in which `function2` is defined does not contain definition of object1. Then when you try to access object1.object2 it throws error because object1 is not defined

Comment: Also the objects are not constructed on parse, only when invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Following would work:

```js
var object1 = {
  object2: {
    function1: function(a, b, c, d, e) {
      //do some stuff with those parameters
      console.log('values are ' + a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c + ' ' + d);
    },
    function2: function(a, b, c, d, e) {
        object1.object2.function1(2, 3, 4, 5);
    }
  }
}
object1.object2.function2();
```

Basically at the time that you want to call **object1** it does not yet exist. This is the reason you get this error. I just delayed this, by inserting it to a function and explicitly calling it later.

Note that javascript does no parameter checks, just fails if they mismatch.

Comment: Notice: function2 arguments are not used

Answer (score 1):

```
var object1 = {
    object2: {
        function1: function (a, b, c, d, e) {
            //do some stuff with those parameters
            console.log('values are ' + a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c + ' ' + d);
        },
        function2: function () { this.function1(2, 3, 4, 5); return this; }
    }.function2()
}
object1.object2.function1(9, 8, 7, 6, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `function2` as shorthand for `function1` called with predefined arguments, you might use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
object1.object2.function2 = object1.object2.function1.bind(null, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

if you need context, replace the `null` for `object1.object2`

Comment: This seems useful. Thanks.